# Why the Images in a JComponent are not drawn properly at loading?

Tags: java, swing

Why does the `initializeGameField()` function not consistently load images when this program runs? Sometimes it shows no image bound to the `JLabel`, and sometimes it shows all 9 images correctly.
I have printed the image path to verify that it is correct. How can I implement the drag and drop feature to the added images?

```
package game;    
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;    
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class NMMPanel {    
    private JFrame frame;
    private int appWidth = 728;
    private int appHeigth = 828;

    private JPanel topButtonPanel, topLeftPanel, topRightPanel; // main
    private JLayeredPane centerPanel;
    private JTextArea txtLogArea;
    private JButton btnNewButton, btnQuitButton;

    private JPanel user1Panel, user2Panel; // sub panels for user1 and user2
    private JLabel chessBoardLabel, stateLabel;

    private JTextField name1TextField, name2TextField;
    private JDialog newGameDialog;
    private boolean turnOfStarter = true;

    private JLabel[] blacks = null;
    private JLabel[] whites = null;

    private Node[] nodes = new Node[24];

    /**
     * Constructor: components and variables setup.
     */
    public NMMPanel() {
        initializeWindow();
        initializeGameField();
    }

    private void initializeWindow() {
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds((dim.width / 2 - (appWidth / 2)),
                (dim.height / 2 - (appHeigth / 2)), appWidth, appHeigth);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        frame.setTitle("9MM - Nine Men's Morris");

        topButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        topButtonPanel.setBounds(6, 0, 710, 36);
        btnNewButton = new JButton("New");
        btnQuitButton = new JButton("Quit");
        topButtonPanel.add(btnNewButton);
        topButtonPanel.add(btnQuitButton);
        frame.getContentPane().add(topButtonPanel);

        // Add listeners to buttons.
        ButtonListener listenToButton = new ButtonListener();
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(listenToButton);
        btnQuitButton.addActionListener(listenToButton);

        topLeftPanel = new JPanel();
        topLeftPanel.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        topLeftPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        topLeftPanel.setBounds(6, 35, 352, 100);
        frame.getContentPane().add(topLeftPanel);
        topLeftPanel.setLayout(null);

        topRightPanel = new JPanel();
        topRightPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        topRightPanel.setBounds(364, 35, 350, 100);
        frame.getContentPane().add(topRightPanel);
        topRightPanel.setLayout(null);

        centerPanel = new JLayeredPane();
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        centerPanel.setBounds(118, 140, 500, 500);
        frame.getContentPane().add(centerPanel);
        centerPanel.setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon field = createImageIcon("/resources/Spielfeld_roundedCorners.png");
        JLabel feld = new JLabel(field);
        feld.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        centerPanel.add(feld, 2);

        ImageIcon texture = createImageIcon("/resources/Wood.jpg");
        JLabel textureCenter = new JLabel(texture);
        textureCenter.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        centerPanel.add(textureCenter, 3);

        setupEventFields(24);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(6, 645, 710, 149);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        txtLogArea = new JTextArea();
        txtLogArea.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(txtLogArea);

        if (turnOfStarter) {
            txtLogArea.append("Whites turn!\n");
        } else {
            txtLogArea.append("Blacks turn!\n");
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setupEventFields(int counter) {
        initNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            final JLabel interactionFields = new JLabel("FFFF");
            interactionFields.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            interactionFields.setBounds(nodes[i].location.x,
                    nodes[i].location.y, 50, 50);
            interactionFields.setCursor(Cursor
                    .getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

            // TODO : Remove later
            interactionFields.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));

            interactionFields.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("entered here");
                    System.out.println(interactionFields.getLocation());
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Clicked here");

                }

            });
            centerPanel.add(interactionFields, 0);
        }
    }

    private void initNodes() {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;
        nodes[0] = new Node("O_0", x, y);

        x = 225;
        y = 10;
        nodes[1] = new Node("O_1", x, y);

        x = 440;
        y = 10;
        nodes[2] = new Node("O_2", x, y);

        x = 74;
        y = 74;
        nodes[3] = new Node("M_0", x, y);

        x = 225;
        y = 72;
        nodes[4] = new Node("M_1", x, y);

        x = 376;
        y = 74;
        nodes[5] = new Node("M_2", x, y);

        x = 137;
        y = 135;
        nodes[6] = new Node("I_0", x, y);

        x = 225;
        y = 135;
        nodes[7] = new Node("I_1", x, y);

        x = 314;
        y = 136;
        nodes[8] = new Node("I_2", x, y);

        x = 10;
        y = 225;
        nodes[9] = new Node("O_3", x, y);

        x = 72;
        y = 225;
        nodes[10] = new Node("M_3", x, y);

        x = 135;
        y = 225;
        nodes[11] = new Node("I_3", x, y);

        x = 316;
        y = 225;
        nodes[12] = new Node("I_4", x, y);

        x = 378;
        y = 225;
        nodes[13] = new Node("M_4", x, y);

        x = 440;
        y = 225;
        nodes[14] = new Node("O_4", x, y);

        x = 137;
        y = 313;
        nodes[15] = new Node("I_5", x, y);

        x = 225;
        y = 316;
        nodes[16] = new Node("I_6", x, y);

        x = 314;
        y = 314;
        nodes[17] = new Node("I_7", x, y);

        x = 74;
        y = 375;
        nodes[18] = new Node("M_5", x, y);

        x = 225;
        y = 377;
        nodes[19] = new Node("M_6", x, y);

        x = 376;
        y = 376;
        nodes[20] = new Node("M_7", x, y);

        x = 10;
        y = 440;
        nodes[21] = new Node("O_5", x, y);

        x = 225;
        y = 440;
        nodes[22] = new Node("O_6", x, y);

        x = 440;
        y = 440;
        nodes[23] = new Node("O_7", x, y);
    }

    protected Node getNode(Point location) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if ((nodes[i].location.x == location.x)
                    && (nodes[i].location.y == location.y)) {
                return nodes[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
       }
    }

    private void initializeGameField() {
        ImageIcon iconWhite = createImageIcon("/resources/White_Stone.png");
        int space = 10;
        blacks = new JLabel[9];
        whites = new JLabel[9];

        JLabel lblPlayer1 = new JLabel("PLAYER 1");
        lblPlayer1.setBounds(150, 80, 61, 16);
        topLeftPanel.add(lblPlayer1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            final JLabel lblWhite = new JLabel(iconWhite);
            lblWhite.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Clicked");
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Dragged");
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Moved");
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Pressed");
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Released");

                }
            });

            lblWhite.setBounds(space, 25, 50, 50);
            topLeftPanel.add(lblWhite);
            space += 35;
            whites[i] = lblWhite;
        }

        JLabel lblPlayer2 = new JLabel("PLAYER 2");
        lblPlayer2.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblPlayer2.setBounds(150, 80, 61, 16);
        topRightPanel.add(lblPlayer2);

        ImageIcon iconBlack = createImageIcon("/resources/Black_Stone.png");

        space = 10;
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            final JLabel lblBlack = new JLabel(iconBlack);
            lblBlack.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Dragged");
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Moved");
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Pressed");
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Released");
                    super.mouseReleased(e);
                }
            });

            lblBlack.setBounds(space, 25, 50, 50);
            topRightPanel.add(lblBlack);
            space += 35;
            blacks[j] = lblBlack;
            System.out.println(lblBlack);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intermittent nature of the problem suggests a threading issue.

Are you calling the constructor `new NMMPanel();` from the Swing event dispatch thread?
Otherwise, you might be creating all the components from a different thread.
Since Swing methods are not thread safe, you might be creating labels (with icons) while the image icon loading is part-complete.

Normally, the `JLabel` will set itself as the `ImageIcon`'s `ImageObserver`, so that it can receive a message to repaint itself once the images are loaded. If the modifications are not on the event thread, this might not happen.

---

edit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // Set up the frame and add the panel.   
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        NMMPanel panel = new NMMPanel(); 
      } 
    }
 }
```

Comment: yes from another class:
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Set up the frame and add the panel. 
  NMMPanel panel = new NMMPanel();
 }

Comment: Thanks @Sanjay 
How can I implement the drag and drop feature to the added images?